# Boost filtered graph with blacklisted edges

Tags: c++, performance, boost-graph

I want to run Dijkstra on a graph with blacklisted edges, i.e., I want to compute shortest paths that do not use those links.
For the moment, I first define the filter:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int> > graph_t;
```

struct BlackListEdgeConstraint
    {
    private:
        std::set blackList;
        graph_t* g;

```
public:

    BlackListEdgeConstraint():blackList(std::set<Edge>() ),g(NULL){};

    BlackListEdgeConstraint(std::set<Edge>& list, graph_t* g_) : blackList(list), g(g_)
    {
    }

    /**
     * This is the "predicate function" used by boost::filtered_graph (
     *  see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/graph/doc/filtered_graph.html )
     *  It it returns true, the edge is included in the filtered graph, otherwise it is excluded.
     */
    bool operator()(const boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::edge_descriptor& e) const
    {
        Edge edge(source(e,*g), target(e,*g) );
        //Include the edge if it's not in the blacklist.
        return blackList.find( edge ) == blackList.end();
    }
};
```

and then I do this in may `main(...)` function

```
... I fill the graph g ...
std::set<Edge> blacklist; blacklist.insert( Edge(0,1)  );
BlackListEdgeConstraint filter(blacklist, &g);
boost::filtered_graph<graph_t, BlackListEdgeConstraint> filtered(g, filter);
... I run Dikjstra on the filtered graph ...
```

Now, what I did works, but it is weird. Indeed, I first create an edge between vertex 0 and 1. Then, inside the `operator() (...)`, I have an `edge_descriptor` instead of an `Edge` (if I put Edge as parameter, the compiler complains as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806455/boost-applying-dijkstra-shortest-path-to-filtered-graph/45554599#45554599), so I guess `boost` is performing some conversion somewhere and for a reason I do not know). Then, I retrieve again the vertices 0 and 1 inside `operator() (...)` and I reconstruct the `Edge`. You understand that I am taking a long tour to do something that would be easy if only the `operator()(..)` accepted directly `Edge`.

Do you think I can do the same operations in a more elegant and efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

What you basically ask has little to do with boost graph. You want to be able to lookup a pair of vertex-descriptors, efficiently.

The deciding factor will be the choice of data structure for the blacklist.

> As a side note, you do **not** insert `Edge` objects into the graph. The graph model you chose is an adjacency-list so it stores lists of adjacent vertices for each vertex.
>
> The `pair<int,int>` is merely a convenience type that is used for easily initializing the graph. You could do without it entirely.

After thinking about the possible choices I don't think there's a swifter way.

- At certain, large, scales, you might get higher effective performance

  - using a blacklist that is itself represented as an adjacency-list (e.g. `std::map<source_vertex, std::list<target_vertex> >`) or
  - to use an `unordered_set<>`.

  Both optimizations are unlikely to yield significant difference unless at large scale.
- you might benefit from locality-of-reference by using a `boost::container::flat_set`

### Is The Cost Real?

If you think that "constructing the `Edge`" is a waste of resources, forget about that: it's a POD type (`std::pair<int, int>`) and as such has only trivial constructor/destructors. Seeing that `set<Edge>` is a template class, most operations on it can be inlined. The compiler will inline away the method call, enregister the arguments, remove redundant load/store cycles and effectively generate optimal code:

```
#include <set>
#include <utility>

using Edge = std::pair<int, int>;
using Blacklist = std::set<Edge>;

struct Pred {
    Blacklist blacklist { { 
        { 92, 29 },
        { 74, 92 },
        { 86, 6 },
        { 67, 35 },
        { 59, 4 },
        { 66, 13 },
        { 82, 37 },
        { 51, 94 },
        { 32, 6 }
    } };

    bool operator()(int source, int target) const {
        return blacklist.end() != blacklist.find(Edge {source, target});
    }
};
```

**<kbd>[View Disassembly Live On Godbolt GCC Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/BpcsBS)</kbd>**

> Pro tip: Click <kbd>`#`</kbd> button on the Clang disassembly to see optimizer comments

[image]

**Summary** The cost of the `Edge` type is non-existent. Any real cost would be down to using `boost::source()` and `boost::target()` on the `edge_descriptor`.

Seeing that your edge container selector is `listS`, your edge containers are node-based, meaning that the edge-descriptor is stable, and basically a type-erased reference to the edge object. Calling `boost::source(e, g)` does little more than casting the descriptor and dereferencing. Depending on how it's used, the compiler *might* even be able to see through these indirections.

If that cost is not to your liking, tweak the Graph type :) (Your use case *might* warrant an EdgeList concept instead, or benefit from using a node-based edge container etc.).